# RethinkDB grouping and defining output

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a table that contains documents that look similar to this:

```
{
"title": "title 2",
"content": "This far, no further!",
"category": "Fiction"
}
```

This is the query I'm using:

```
r.table('posts').group('title').map(lambda item:
    {'items': item['title']}
).run())
```

This is the output:

```
{
  "title 1" : [
    {
      "items" : "title 1"
    },
    {
      "items" : "title 1"
    }
  ],
  "Title 2" : [
    {
      "items" : "Title 2"
    },
    {
      "items" : "Title 2"
    },
    {
      "items" : "Title 2"
    },
    {
      "items" : "Title 2"
    }
  ],
  "title 3" : [
    {
      "items" : "title 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

However I would like to get an output structure that looks like this:

```
{
  "Title 1" : {
    "item_count" : 3,
    "items" : [
      {
        "items" : "title 1"
      },
      {
        "items" : "title 1"
      },
      {
        "items" : "title 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Title 2" : {
    "item_count" : 2,
    "items" : [
      {
        "items" : "title 2"
      },
      {
        "items" : "title 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Title 3" : {
    "item_count" : 1,
    "items" : [
      {
        "items" : "title 3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How would I create a query to get to this result.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you need to `map` your query after you executing `ungroup` in it.

First, the output of your first query looks incorrect. RethinkDB doesn't wouldn't return an object/dictionary after a `map` operation, it would return an array. The output I got from your query was the following:

```
[
  {
    "group":  "title 1" ,
    "reduction": [
      {
        "items":  "title 1"
      } ,
      {
        "items":  "title 1"
      }
    ]
  } ,
  {
    "group":  "title 2" ,
    "reduction": [
      {
        "items":  "title 2"
      } ,
      {
        "items":  "title 2"
      }
    ]
  } ,
  ...
]
```

If what you want is a property called `items` along with a count of how many items that `items` property has, you can do the following:

```
// THIS IS JAVASCRIPT
r.table('posts')
 .group('title')
 .map(function (item) {
    return {
      items: item('title')
    }
 })
 .ungroup()
 .map(function (row) { 
    return {
      'title': row('group'),
      'items': row('reduction'),
      'count': row('reduction').count()
    }
  })
```

The result of that query will be the following:

```
[
  {
    "count": 2 ,
    "items": [
      {
        "items":  "title 1"
      },
      {
        "items":  "title 1"
      }
    ],
    "title":  "title 1"
    },
  {
    "count": 2 ,
    "items": [
      {
        "items":  "title 2"
      } ,
      {
        "items":  "title 2"
      }
    ] ,
    "title":  "title 2"
  },
  ...
]
```

If you want to then turn that query into an object/dictionary so that you can call up a post by it's title, you can turn that array of posts into an object, by using `r.object` along with `r.args`. The complete query will look like this:

```
// THIS IS JAVASCRIPT
r.table('posts')
 .group('title')
 .map(function (item) {
    return {
      items: item('title')
    }
 })
 .ungroup()
 .map(function (row) {
    return {
      'title': row('group'),
      'items': row('reduction'),
      'count': row('reduction').count()
    }
  })
  .do(function (rows) {
    return r.object(r.args(rows.concatMap(function (row) {
      return [row('title'), row];
    })));
  })
```

The result of that query will be something like this:

```
{
  "title 1": {
    "count": 2 ,
    "items": [
      {
        "items":  "title 1"
      } ,
      {
        "items":  "title 1"
      }
    ] ,
    "title":  "title 1"
  } ,
  "title 2": {
    "count": 2 ,
    "items": [
      {
        "items":  "title 2"
      } ,
      {
        "items":  "title 2"
      }
    ] ,
    "title":  "title 2"
  } ,
  ...
}
```